# Do Normal Transactions run on the EVM?

Tags: contract-development, evm, accounts, storage-trie

I have read that smart contracts are compiled to bytecode and interpreted by the EVM and this changes the internal state of each node. However, I am not sure if normal transactions from address to address also are run by the EVM which manipulates the state or it is a separate process. I am asking since the storageRoot and codeHash of an account addresses are empty. I guess to summarize how does a normal transaction state change differ from a contract call/deploy state change.

On the same note, storageRoot in the contract address is just used for verification by the nodes that a block is correct by querying the network or its inner state about the hashes in the tree? In itself, the actual storage of the contract state is in each node after running the state change from one block to the other or is it? I would think it doesn't make sense to store the whole state inside the block rather just the hash of the state after running the transactions in the block. I could be completely wrong here.

Sorry for the confusing language.